# Getting run time error 438 when running code in VBA. Complains on "ExcelApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges"

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I´m trying to get this code to work, the purpose is to select a range of hyperlinked excel-files within an excel-file, press the command button and print them. I´ve managed to print once but after that i get run-time error 438. See "**This is where error occur**" above the row in the code below for which the error occur.

I am new to VBA so would appreciate if someone could explain why the error occur and come with a solution.

```
Sub ExportToWordAndPrint()

With Sheets("SOBar")

Const Ttl As String = "Excel Print"
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim FullNameOfFile As String
Dim ExcelApp As Object, MyDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0


If ExcelApp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed on this computer - operation cancelled.", vbCritical + 
vbOKOnly, Ttl
Exit Sub
End If

ExcelApp.Visible = True

Set rng = Selection


For Each cell In rng

With rng

On Error Resume Next
FullNameOfFile = ""
FullNameOfFile = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
On Error GoTo 0

If FullNameOfFile <> "" Then 'cell may not have contained a Hyperlink

    If Dir(FullNameOfFile) <> "" Then 'cell may contain a Hyperlink, but the file itself may not exist

        'Debug.print cell.address & " should print"    'THIS ONE ADDED
        With ExcelApp
            Set MyDoc = .Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FullNameOfFile)
            MyDoc.PrintOut
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
            .ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Else         'THIS ONE ADDED
        'Debug.Print cell.Address & " failed, appears to have wrong filename"
    End If
Else             'THIS ONE ADDED
    'Debug.Print cell.Address & " failed, appears to have no hyperlink"
End If

End With
Next cell

'This is where error occur
ExcelApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set ExcelApp = Nothing

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running this code from Excel or Word?

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But it is for hyperlinked Excel-files (within an excel file) which i want to print using selection & command button. I tried to add Const wdDoNotSaveChanges As Integer = 0 and Option Explicit but then i get other bugs (Range = Nothing). I probably need to practice the basics a bit more...

Comment: Where are you running this code from?

Comment: Running this code from Excel :)

Comment: So what role does MS Word have in this?

Comment: MS word does not have a role. It is only the name for the sub-program which the button calls for. Ignore the comments about ms word, it is a code in VBA (excel) which is used to print hyperlinked excel doucments in a Excel document :)

Comment: Sorry if the code is messy..

Comment: `MS word does not have a role.` Then why are you using `wdDoNotSaveChanges`. It is MS Word constant and not an MS Excel constant. To close the workbook and then quit excel, Try this `MyDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False` Where `MyDoc` is the workbook object and then use `ExcelApp.Quit`

Comment: Replace `.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False` with `MyDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False` and replace `ExcelApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges` with `ExcelApp.Quit`

Comment: Tried your solution, it does not print and it tries to exit the workbook, I tried to remove the whole Excelapp.quit row but now it gets a bug where the first row "Sub ExportToWordAndPrint ()" : MyDoc = Nothing

Comment: Did you try and put a breakpoint on `DoEvents`? It should print. Also I do not see `MyDoc = Nothing`? BTW it should be `Set MyDoc = Nothing` And you do not need to set it to nothing from excel itself. VBA will automatically set it to nothing

Answer (score 1):

> MS word does not have a role. It is only the name for the sub-program which the button calls for. Ignore the comments about ms word, it is a code in VBA (excel) which is used to print hyperlinked excel doucments in a Excel document :) – David44 15 mins ago

You have mixed up MS Excel and MS Word? `ExcelApp` is the `Excel Application` and your message box says something else `MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed on this computer....`

Also `wdDoNotSaveChanges` is MS Word constant and not an MS Excel constant. I would recommend adding `Option Explicit` at the top as well

I would also recommend not to work with `Selection` but with a proper range object. If you still want to work with the selection then check if it is a valid selection as shown in the code below.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim FullNameOfFile As String

    '~~> Use this object with the right range object
    '~~> instead of using `Selection`
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOBar")

    '~~> Instead of selection use something like this
    '~~> Change it to the relevant range
    'Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10")

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Selection

    For Each aCell In rng
        FullNameOfFile = ""

        On Error Resume Next
        FullNameOfFile = aCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        On Error GoTo 0

        If FullNameOfFile <> "" Then
            If Dir(FullNameOfFile) <> "" Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullNameOfFile)
                wb.PrintOut
                DoEvents
                wb.Close (False)
            End If
        End If
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

Avoid using `ExcelApp.Quit` from the same project. You may be working on some other workbook and you may lose those changes. If you still want to use it then be aware of possible repurcussions.

Comment: Hello! No i have not mixed up word and excel. I got the code from a friend which thought i needed to print hyperlinked word-docs and then modified it to excel. I would like to use selection since i have ~3000 hyperlinks in the document i¨m working in.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is that what you are trying?